# Sort each column of table

Tags: postgresql

Hey I am new to sql/postgreSql. I was given a problem, I would like to have suggestions on how to do it. Below is the table I was given.

```
Student Maths   Physics Chemistry
Joe     80      52       69
Steff   50      90       95
James   62      98       42
```

I need to query the above table such that it sorts the students in the descending order according to their marks. See below.

```
Maths   Physcis Chemistry
Joe     James   Steff
James   Steff   Joe
Steff   Joe     James
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yeah. But I was able to get only one column. What if there are more columns and I would like to know on how to do it? Is there anything in PostgreSQL that return number of columns in a table?

Answer (score 0):

The key to the answer is [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).

```
with orders as (
    select
        student,
        row_number() over (order by maths desc) as m,
        row_number() over (order by physics desc) as p,
        row_number() over (order by chemistry desc) as c
    from ratings
)
select
    m.student as Maths,
    p.student as Physics,
    c.student as Chemistry
from orders as m
join orders as p on m.m=p.p
join orders as c on m.m=c.c
order by m.m;
```